# How to infer return type of a generic function with default types

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
declare function test<A = number, B = string>(a: A, b: B): { a: A, b: B }

type T1 = ReturnType<typeof test>         // { a: unknown; b: unknown }
type T2 = ReturnType<typeof test<number>> // { a: number; b: string }
```

Why can't TS infer `T1` correctly? Is it a bug? Are there any workarounds besides `T2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript infers the type `unknown` correctly, since the types of `A` and `B` are not defined as long as the function is not called with arguments. You must define the types with `extends` like this:

```
declare function test<A extends number = number, B extends string = string>(a: A, b: B): { a: A, b: B }
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but do you find behavior of inferring `T1` and `T2` inconsistent? I mean, shouldn't `T2` be `{ a: number, b: unknown }` by the same logic?

Comment: Or maybe if you could write `type T1 = ReturnType<typeof test<>>` and it would use default types? That would be nice.

Comment: Maybe. But when you specify the type of an argument, typescript infers the type of the rest to "typify" the optional arguments and types, and so on, the entire function. Meanwhile, the types will be `unknown`.